# Blank app due to terminal error. How to fix this issue to get the app page

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am in the middle of a react native app development. I am running yarn and expo for the simulation. I have installed all the requirements and the codes seem correct as per my knowledge. But I am getting terminal error and due to which I am failing to see my app and only appears blank.

I am getting the following error in the terminal while running yarn and then pressing w for website version:

I did: yarn start -> p`enter code here`ressed w to see webapp:

```
› Webpack waiting on http://127.0.0.1:19006 
› Expo Webpack (web) is in beta, and subjectto breaking changes!
Web Bundling complete 9367ms
./node_modules/react-native-maps/index.js:24
"export 'Animated' was not found in './lib/components/MapView'
  22 | 
  23 | export { Marker, Overlay };
  24 | export { Animated, MAP_TYPES, ProviderPropType };     
  25 | 
  26 | export const PROVIDER_GOOGLE = MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE;
  27 | export const PROVIDER_DEFAULT = MapView.PROVIDER_DEFAULT;
./node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/components/MapMarker.js:79:12
"export 'ColorPropType' was not found in 'react-native-web/dist/index'
  77 |    * which can be customized by this color. Ignored if a custom marker is being used.
```

What shall i do in this case as I am getting long list of error saying export not found like above though I have it.

Answer (score 0):

I once encountered a similar error that was resolved by manually installing the libraries stated in the error log.

If the list of libraries is too long, I would try to clear the cache

```
yarn cache clean
```

and issue another library install command

```
yarn install
```

Comment: I tried to run the commands you suggested for, but still I am getting the same issues. How to install the libraries anually? Do you have any suggestion or resources to provide.

Comment: I have tried out with the commands that you suggested but still I am getting the same errors in the terminal. How to resolve this. How to install the libraries manually? Do you have any resources or something that helps me out? If so please provide me with it. Some kind of repository.

Comment: By manually I meant something like
"yarn install module_name"
Sorry, I don't have any resources to provide on this matter